# Working with ScrollView in android

Tags: android, listview, layout, landscape-portrait, android-imagebutton

I am creating a gallery about some places. My app contains a ScrollViewwith roughly about 20 image buttons of different places and if the user clicks any of the place, they will be taken to another screen with the information about the place.

So far, I have been able to complete my app, the only problem I have is that the image buttons of the places are placed one after another but what I really want is to have them side by side if there is room. For example, currently my app looks like this;

[image]

There is plenty of space being wasted on the screen to the left and right, if possible, I want to make the layout of my app something like this;

[image]

and when in landspace mode, I want to have something like this.
[image]

also, if possible, depending on the phone screen size, I want more images to fit in the current view. e.g. say for example, if the app is opened in a 10" tablet, then rather then having 2 imagebuttons on the same line, I want have more.

My XML code is;

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/london"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/london"
            android:src="@drawable/london" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/paris"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paris"
            android:src="@drawable/paris" />

....


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/berlin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/berlin"
            android:src="@drawable/berlin" />
```

Thanks for your help, if I have not explained myself clearly, please let me know and I will try my best to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use-case for a `GridView`. The good news is you can probably reuse your adapter and only have to replace the `ListView` with a `GridView`. Here is a link to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

--EDIT--

If you want to replace a `ScrollView`, you have to change your approach.

In your xml file you can replace all the ImageButtons with a single `GridView`:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvCities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</GridView>
```

you should have a new layout file called `city_button`:

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_discription"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ImageButton>
```

You should create a new class: `CityAdapter`

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.znappie.activities.R;

public class CityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int[] imageIds;
    private LayoutInflater inflate;
    private Resources resources;

    public CityAdapter(int[] imageIds, LayoutInflater inflate,
            Resources resources) {
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
        this.inflate = inflate;
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imageIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.city_button, parent);
        }
        ((ImageButton) convertView).setImageDrawable(resources
                .getDrawable(imageIds[position]));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

You can then use this from you Main Activity:

```
int[] ids = {R.drawable.berlin, R.drawable.london, ...};
            GridView cities = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvCities);
            cities.setAdapter(new CityAdapter(ids, getLayoutInflater(), getResources()));
```

Comment: I am fairly new to java, so please bare with me. Currently I am using a <ScrollView ....imagebuttons..... </ScrollView>. Should I place the ScrollView with GridView? like this <GridView....imagebuttons..... </GridView>

Comment: I thought you said u used a `ListView`. You can not simple replace a `ScrollView` with a `ListView`. I will edit my answer

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I have used ScrollView.